# Gems not installing when creating D:\sites>rails new simple_cms -d mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, rubygems

I have installed gems and when I type gem -v it all comes through OK.  I have Windows 10, classroom environment, Ruby v 2.2;   But when I run to test or do the above command I get the following.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies.....

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/rake-11.2.2.gem)
Using i18n 0.7.0

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/json-1.8.3.gem)

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/minitest-5.9.0.gem)
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0.gem)

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/pkg-config-1.1.7.gem)
Using rack 1.6.4

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/mime-types-data-3.2016.0521.gem)
Using arel 6.0.3

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2.gem)
Using bundler 1.11.2

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/byebug-9.0.5.gem)
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/execjs-2.7.0.gem)
Using thor 0.19.1

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.2.gem)

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/multi_json-1.12.1.gem)

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/mysql2-0.4.4-x86-mingw32.gem)

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/sass-3.4.22.gem)

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/tilt-2.0.5.gem)

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/gems/turbolinks-source-5.0.0.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (11.2.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '11.2.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score -1):

Please follow below description this will resolve your problem.

Steps are simple:

> Step 1: Obtain the new trust certificate

We need to download [AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubygems/rubygems/master/lib/rubygems/ssl_certs/AddTrustExternalCARoot-2048.pem).

Use the above link and place/save this file somewhere you can later find easily (eg. your Desktop).

IMPORTANT: File must have .pem as extension. Browsers like Chrome will try to save it as plain text file. Ensure you change the filename to have .pem in it after you have downloaded it.

> Step 2: Locate RubyGems certificate directory in your installation

In order for us copy this file, we need to know where to put it.

Depending on where you installed Ruby, the directory will be different.

Take for example the default installation of Ruby 2.1.5, placed in C:\Ruby21

Open a Command Prompt and type in:

C:>gem which rubygems
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb
Now, let's locate that directory. From within the same window, enter the path part up to the file extension, but using backslashes instead:

C:>start C:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\2.1.0\rubygems
This will open a Explorer window inside the directory we indicated.

> Step 3: Copy new trust certificate

Now, locate ssl_certs directory and copy the .pem file we obtained from previous step inside.

It will be listed with other files like GeoTrustGlobalCA.pem.

> Step 4: Profit

There is actually no step 4. You should be able to install Ruby gems without issues now.

[more details on github](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88)